# Corona sdk linear color ramp?

Tags: lua, coronasdk

Ok, I have a very, very large background image, well not an image but a rectangle colored blue:

```
bg2 =display.newRect(0,0,20000,20000)
bg2.y=10000
bg2:setFillColor( 0 , 0, 225)
```

Is it possible to make the rectangle not just one solid color, but a linear color ramp from black to blue? In other words, the color fades from black to blue vertically. I don't want to use an image, because it would be way too large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a [gradient](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/ShapeObject/setFillColor.html#gradient-fill) [fill color](http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/path.html#fill-and-stroke), such as this.

```
local black = {0, 0, 0}
local blue = {0, 0, 1}
local g = {type="gradient", color1=black, color2=blue}

bg2:setFillColor(g)
```

Comment: @SamHogan: Please accept the answer, if it satisfies your need.